# Can't view a .ps file by ghostscript through the command line (Windows 10)

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, gmt

I am learning how to make maps with a GMT open source software and as a result, I get a map.ps file. To view a map.ps, I need to use Ghostscript (via cmd), however, a computer does not even recognize that I have Ghostscript and GSView installed.

So my question is, how I could call a GSView from a command line to open a .ps image? And what could be possibly wrong in my efforts?
[Command line example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHbE4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first problem is that Ghostscript isn't called 'gs' on Windows, its either gswin32, gswin32c, gswin64 or gswin64c depending on whether you have installed a 32 or 64-bit version and want to run the command shell version or the windowed version of Ghostscript.

Next, you almost certainly don't have the Ghostscript or GSView installation directories in your PATH environment variable. If you don't add the directories containing those applications to your PATH, then they won't be found. (the PATH environment variable is a list of directories Windows will search when trying to find a named application to execute)

Alternatively you can start the application by changing to the directory containing the executable (the current directory is always included in PATH), or you can specify the complete pathname, eg

```
"C:\windows (x86)\gs\gs9.19\bin\gswin32"
```